# How to transfer one line to another in Unix

Tags: linux, unix

Suppose i have the following input:

```
BSCTMC             A13728,  J02448,  L13668,  M14730,  A12868,  C11347,
                   L14203,  C02285,  A14419,  BO0797,  S12666,  M12653,
                   D04841,  S02825,  T14713,  L15004,  C01972,  E12057,
                   S13319
```

I want the A13728, J02448 (and so on) up to S13319 on the same line instead. I want to create a script that saves it to a text file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily with:

```
tr -d '\n' < filename.txt > filename-oneline.txt; mv filename-oneline.txt filename.txt
```

Comment: Uh, no. A `<` redirection would have been more appropriate.

Comment: @Matthew What if there are lines that i want to remain to have spaces? This codes converts ALL of my text into single line. =)

Comment: @jonas, what is the criteria for the lines that you want to have spaces? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: There are particular lines that i want to merge and there are lines that i want to remain untouched.

Comment: For example i have 15 lines, I want to merge lines 3,4,5 into a single line and remain the rest untouchable. Is that possible?

Comment: will it always be lines 3,4,5?

Comment: Not all the times buddy. But can you give me an example code =)

Comment: You'd probably have to run a scripting language to do what you're looking for, like perl or python.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with sed by only replacing newlines when the line ends with a comma (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a; /,$/ { N; ba }; s/\n//g' infile
```

If you also want to compress the whitespace from the alignment, add `s/,   */,  /g`to the sed expressions, i.e.:

```
sed ':a; /,$/ { N; ba }; s/\n//g; s/,   */  /g' infile
```

Output:

```
BSCTMC             A13728,  J02448,  L13668,  M14730,  A12868,  C11347,  L14203,  C02285,  A14419,  BO0797,  S12666,  M12653,  D04841,  S02825,  T14713,  L15004,  C01972,  E12057,  S13319
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
$ xargs < infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the space in-between, you can use `awk` :

```
awk '{printf "%s", $0}' inputfile > outputfile
```

Results :

```
BSCTMC             A13728,  J02448,  L13668,  M14730,  A12868,  C11347,                   L14203,  C02285,  A14419,  BO0797,  S12666,  M12653,                   D04841,  S02825,  T14713,  L15004,  C01972,  E12057,                   S13319
```