# How to merge several lines in the same textfile in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have a text file and I want to put the contents of the lines into 1 single line. For example.

I have a text file named `WEEE.txt` and it contains:

```
BSS100  PROF  K


BSS101  TREES E
BSS102  TRUNK R, S,
              V, R,
              T
BSS103  TEXT  KE
BSS104  WEEW  KER,
              SSS
```

I want to have the output like:

```
BSS100  PROF  K
BSS101  TREES E
BSS102  TRUNK R, S, V, R, T
BSS103  TEXT  KE
BSS104  WEEW  KER, SSS
```

But hey. This is the portion of the project that I am currently doing. This is the REAL THING! I cite the first on on the top as an example but i cant do it. :) Please help me! (Supposedly this is BSC.txt)

```
BSC195






PROFILE             VDU0 , VDU1 , VDU2 , VDU3 , VDU4 , VDU5 ,
                    VDU6 , VDU7 , VDU8 , VDU9 , VDU10, VDU11,
                    VDU12, VDU13, VDU14, VDU15, CAL0 , VTP
MOKAS               NOKIA1
CBCERTCK            D10393
NUTRDM              NUPADM
SPMNGT              SPMNGT
NFTRA
RCCFVS              RCCMLA
TRAFAD              TRAFAD
NOCORF              NOCOSS
NETWCH              NETWCH
BSCOP5              BSCOPT
MMOPTI              MMOPTI
SYSSDE              SYSOP1
SMCSOC              SMCSOC
LRCCMM              ITNCCM
VENFVD              VENNSN
BSCGBF              BSCRHM
BSHGTD              BSCLOC, P10203
BSCASD              BSCEMR
LSCRIPT
BSCGVS              A13728, J02448, L13668, M14730, A12868, C11347,
                    L14203, C02285, A14419, B00797, S12666, M12653,
                    D04841, S02825, T14713, L15004, C01972, E12057,
                    S13319
LSNCMM              F02642
LSYSCRIPT           CATSYS
```

This is what i want to happen:

```
BSC195






PROFILE             VDU0 , VDU1 , VDU2 , VDU3 , VDU4 , VDU5 ,VDU6 , VDU7 , VDU8 , VDU9 , VDU10, VDU11, VDU12, VDU13, VDU14, VDU15, CAL0 , VTP *
MOKAS               NOKIA1
CBCERTCK            D10393
NUTRDM              NUPADM
SPMNGT              SPMNGT
NFTRA
RCCFVS              RCCMLA
TRAFAD              TRAFAD
NOCORF              NOCOSS
NETWCH              NETWCH
BSCOP5              BSCOPT
MMOPTI              MMOPTI
SYSSDE              SYSOP1
SMCSOC              SMCSOC
LRCCMM              ITNCCM
VENFVD              VENNSN
BSCGBF              BSCRHM
BSHGTD              BSCLOC, P10203
BSCASD              BSCEMR
LSCRIPT
BSCGVS              A13728, J02448, L13668, M14730, A12868, C1198, L14203, C02285, A14419, B00797, S12666, M12653,D04841, S02825, T14713, L15004, C01972, E12057, S13319 *
LSNCMM              F02642
LSYSCRIPT           CATSYS
```

Note: The * means that i want that on a single line. From BSCGVS up to S133319 on a one single line. as well as in PROFILE up to VTP. Is is still possible?
Another Note: this just a small portion of my data. Please help. I dont know what to do. Because this will be my input in my database. =) Please help =)

Comment: You can certainly do it in a scripting language. Personally, I'd use perl. It could also be done with sed. Or with an emacs macro ;0)

Comment: It can be done in a host of languages.  So the answer is yes, it is possible, obviously.  Do you have a real question?  Or is this just one of those "do my homework for me please" questions?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432743/how-to-transfer-one-line-to-another-in-unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432743/how-to-transfer-one-line-to-another-in-unix) by the same author.

Comment: Nothing for now. Can i use sed, awk, or cat? or theres other way around for satisfy my conditions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed ':a; N;/\n\S/! {s/\n */ /;ba}; P;D' WEEE.txt
```

Comment: Hey man. I updated my post. What if my situation is like that? Can u help me? :)

Comment: @sudo_O, Please take in consideration the fact that at first there were different strings in this file. You can find them in the first edition of the question. Then jonas changed the file significantly. In your example you use the changed file. And sidharth's answer was to the first version of the file. If it is you who downvoted this answer then it is for a wrong reason.

Comment: Yes, that answer was to the first version of the file. Anyway now I have modified it according to the latest version. Thanks @skwllsp

Comment: @skwllsp you are completely wrong, sidharth answer was wrong at the time so I downvoted it and left a comment. He has since updated his answer to match the updated question so may downvote is now an update. This is how SO overflow works.

Comment: @sudo_O, I am talking about your example http://ideone.com/hyJjjg. You took his first answer and the second version of file. I see this when open your link.

Comment: @sudo_O, I took the first version of question and the first version of sidharth's answer. And tested his sed script. And it worked fine. It you who are wrong.

Comment: @skwllsp maybe you should do some reading on meta about voting you are clearing confused. I appreciate that the question was changed so I notified sidharth and he update his answer. This is the correct procedure. What is your problem?

Comment: Chill brothers. Take a look at my post. I updated it. I need your expert help. =)

Comment: @jonas : Updated the answer according to ur latest question. But this would delete all the blank lines in the file. Hope that is not a problem.

Comment: I just tried it man. It fits what i want to happen. Thank you! You help me alot. My father will kiss me if he sees what i've done. Thanks to you! :)))

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED#2 and IMPROVED** I overcomplicated the solution. Here is the simplified one

If You need a pure `bash` solution try the script above. It uses only internal `bash` function so it does not call any external programmes (no `fork` at all).

```
while read; do
  #Skip empty lines
  [[ $REPLY =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]] && continue
  # Chomp all but one leading spaces
  [[ $REPLY =~ ^[[:space:]]+(.*) ]] && REPLY=" ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  # Chomp trailing spaces
  [[ $REPLY =~ (.*[^[:space:]])[[:space:]]+$ ]] && REPLY="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  echo -e "$REPLY\c"
  # Add LF at the end if not finished with ','
  [[ $REPLY =~ ,$ ]] || echo
done <<XXX
BSS100  PROF  K



BSS101  TREES E
BSS102  TRUNK R, S, 
              V, R,
              T
BSS103  TEXT  KE
BSS104  WEEW  KER,
              SSS
XXX
```

Output:

```
BSS100  PROF  K
BSS101  TREES E
BSS102  TRUNK R, S, V, R, T
BSS103  TEXT  KE
BSS104  WEEW  KER, SSS
```

What is does:

At first the file is redirected to the while loop. It is better then commonly used `cat file|while` as it does not do double `fork` (one for `cat` and one for the `bash` running the `while` loop). Here I used the "here-is-the-document" feature to make more plausible example. But you can use the `while ... done <filename` form as well.

The `while` loop processes all lines from the file. If there is no further arg to `read` it places the read line to `REPLY` env var.

Then`REPLY` is checked if it contains (only) zero or more white space characters (space or tab). If so, the loop continued.

Then `REPLY` is checked if it starts with one or more white spaces. If so the multiple white spaces replaced by one space character.

Then `REPLY` is checked if it ends with one or more white spaces. If so the multiple white spaces are eliminated.

Then `REPLY` is printed without linefeed.

Then `REPLY` is checked if it ends with a `,`. If not so then a line feed is printer.

References: [bash(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), [regex(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/regex), [fork(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)

Comment: It look like i didnt understand this thing =) BTW thanks for you help. I'm only a newbie in Unix commands. So can you still help me on my updated post? Take a look at my post. I updated it.

Comment: @jonas: updated. I added more explanateion. BTW thanks for the question! I learned using =~ in bash!

Comment: @jonas: I simplified the solution. Using an explicit filehandle was not needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
awk '/^BS/{printf "%s%s ",s,$0;s="\n";next}{sub(/^\s*/,"");printf "%s ",$0}' file
BSS100  PROF  K
BSS101  TREES E
BSS102  TRUNK R, S, V, R, T
BSS103  TEXT  KE
BSS104  WEEW  KER, SSS
```

Comment: Thanks sudo_O. But take a look at my updated post. That is my problem. I have a bunch of that. How can i make the indented ones into a single line (Take a look at the post). =)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^\S/{printf "%s%s",rs,$0; rs="\n"; next} {$1=" "$1;printf "%s",$0} END{print ""}' file
```

Try it when your input file does and doesn't end in a BS-started line:

```
$ cat file
BSS100  PROF  K
BSS101  TREES E
BSS102  TRUNK R, S,
              V, R,
              T
BSS103  TEXT  KE
BSS104  WEEW  KER,
              SSS
$
$ awk '/^\S/{printf "%s%s",rs,$0; rs="\n"; next} {$1=" "$1;printf "%s",$0} END{print ""}' file
BSS100  PROF  K
BSS101  TREES E
BSS102  TRUNK R, S, V, R, T
BSS103  TEXT  KE
BSS104  WEEW  KER, SSS
$
$ cat file1
BSS100  PROF  K
BSS101  TREES E
BSS102  TRUNK R, S,
              V, R,
              T
BSS103  TEXT  KE
BSS104  WEEW  KER,
              SSS
BSS104  WEEW  FOO
$
$ awk '/^\S/{printf "%s%s",rs,$0; rs="\n"; next} {$1=" "$1;printf "%s",$0} END{print ""}' file1
BSS100  PROF  K
BSS101  TREES E
BSS102  TRUNK R, S, V, R, T
BSS103  TEXT  KE
BSS104  WEEW  KER, SSS
BSS104  WEEW  FOO
```

Comment: Thanks sir. Take a look at my updated post. That is my big problem =) Hope you can help sir. :)

Comment: Did you try the script I posted above? It should work as-is except for leaving all those blank lines after your first line which you had specifically removed in your original output. If you need them to remain it's a trivial tweak to just print blank lines.

Comment: Everything seems to be perfect by now. =))\

Comment: If you have an answer you're happy with, remember to click on the check mark next to it so others don't waste their time trying to help you come up with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not good at `awk` but anyway:

```
>awk '/^BSS/ {if (NR>1) printf("\n"); printf("%s", $0);} !/^BSS/ {printf(", %s", $1); } END {printf("\n");} ' WEEE.txt
BSS100   K
BSS101   E
BSS102   R, V, S
BSS103   KE
BSS104   KER, SSS
```

**UPDATE**

```
>awk '/^BSS/ {if (NR>1) printf("\n"); for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) gsub(",$", "", $i);  printf("%s %s %s", $1, $2, $3);  for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) printf(", %s", $i); } !/^BSS/ { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {gsub(",$", "", $i); printf(", %s", $i);}  }END {printf("\n");}  ' WEEE.txt
BSS100 PROF K
BSS101 TREES E
BSS102 TRUNK R, S, V, R, T
BSS103 TEXT KE
BSS104 WEEW KER, SSS
```

Comment: Hey man. I updated my post. What if my situation is like that? Can u help me? :)

Comment: Take a look at a new version

Comment: Hey buddy. What does this command does? 

for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) gsub(",$", "", $i);  printf("%s %s %s", $1, $2, $3);  for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) printf(", %s", $i); }

Comment: Take a look at this page, please http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html

Comment: Its not working when I integrate the command on my project. Can I request for a chat so I can clearly discuss my thoughts? =)

Comment: It is working. I have tested the commmnd with your file. What is not working after the integration?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29585/discussion-between-jonas-and-skwllsp)

Comment: Hey sir skwllsp! Take a look at my post. I updated it. I need you expert help sir! =)